How to create a new list[list[str]] column based on another list[str] column without iterating over rows
(Please edit the title if you find a more suiting one)
I have following dataframe that contains grouped records:
Table 1
┌──────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ str_id                   ┆ source          ┆ id          │
│ ---                      ┆ ---             ┆ ---         │
│ list[str]                ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[i64]   │
╞══════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ ["s1_5", "s2_3", "s3_3"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [5, 9, 14]  │
│ ["s1_2", "s2_2", "s3_2"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [2, 8, 13]  │
│ ["s1_3", "s2_4", "s3_4"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [3, 10, 15] │
│ ["s1_1", "s2_1", "s3_1"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [1, 7, 12]  │
│ ["s1_4", "s3_6"]         ┆ ["1", "6"]      ┆ [4, 17]     │
│ ["s2_5", "s3_5"]         ┆ ["5", "6"]      ┆ [11, 16]    │
│ ["s1_6"]                 ┆ ["1"]           ┆ [6]         │
└──────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┘

I want to create a new column called m_group that contains int values linking records within group, preceded by f"{source}_". I map only source==1 to other sources, therefore records for source==1 will have multiple links, while other sources will only have one. Example: source==1, m_group==5_3 links to source==5 m_group==1_3 The output is following (please disregard column m_status for now):
Table 2
┌─────┬──────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ str_id       ┆ source         ┆ m_group        ┆ m_status       │
│ --- ┆ ---          ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ str          ┆ str            ┆ list[str]      ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════╪══════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ s1_1         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_3", "6_3"] ┆ ["6_1", "5_1"] │
│ 2   ┆ s1_2         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ ["6_1", "5_1"] │
│ 3   ┆ s1_3         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] ┆ ["6_1", "5_1"] │
│ 4   ┆ s1_4         ┆ 1              ┆ ["6_4"]        ┆ ["6_1"]        │
│ 5   ┆ s1_5         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_0", "6_0"] ┆ ["6_1", "5_1"] │
│ 6   ┆ s1_6         ┆ 1              ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 7   ┆ s2_1         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_3"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 8   ┆ s2_2         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 9   ┆ s2_3         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_0"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 10  ┆ s2_4         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_2"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 11  ┆ s2_5         ┆ 5              ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 12  ┆ s3_1         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_3"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 13  ┆ s3_2         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 14  ┆ s3_3         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_0"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 15  ┆ s3_4         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_2"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 16  ┆ s3_5         ┆ 6              ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 17  ┆ s3_6         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_4"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
└─────┴──────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘

To achieve this, I iterate over rows in Table 1 and create a list of lists with these links, that I later append to the dataframe and explode().
Code 1
m_g = []
num = 0
for row in df.iter_rows(named=True):
    temp = []
    if "1" in row["source"]:
        for x in row["source"]:
            if x == "1":
                temp.append([f"{x}_" + str(num) for x in row["source"] if x!='1'])
            else:
                temp.append(["1_" + str(num)])
        m_g.append(temp)
        num += 1
    else:
        for x in row["source"]:
            temp.append([])
        m_g.append(temp)

# m_g:
# [[['5_0', '6_0'], ['1_0'], ['1_0']], [['5_1', '6_1'], ['1_1'], ['1_1']], [['5_2', '6_2'],
 ['1_2'], ['1_2']], [['5_3', '6_3'], ['1_3'], ['1_3']], [['6_4'], ['1_4']], [[], []], [[]]]


I add column m_group using list m_g and obtain following dataframe:
Table 3
df = df.with_columns(pl.Series(name="m_group", values=m_g))

┌──────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ str_id                   ┆ source          ┆ id          ┆ m_group                         │
│ ---                      ┆ ---             ┆ ---         ┆ ---                             │
│ list[str]                ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[list[str]]                 │
╞══════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["s1_5", "s2_3", "s3_3"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [5, 9, 14]  ┆ [["5_0", "6_0"], ["1_0"], ["1_… │
│ ["s1_2", "s2_2", "s3_2"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [2, 8, 13]  ┆ [["5_1", "6_1"], ["1_1"], ["1_… │
│ ["s1_3", "s2_4", "s3_4"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [3, 10, 15] ┆ [["5_2", "6_2"], ["1_2"], ["1_… │
│ ["s1_1", "s2_1", "s3_1"] ┆ ["1", "5", "6"] ┆ [1, 7, 12]  ┆ [["5_3", "6_3"], ["1_3"], ["1_… │
│ ["s1_4", "s3_6"]         ┆ ["1", "6"]      ┆ [4, 17]     ┆ [["6_4"], ["1_4"]]              │
│ ["s2_5", "s3_5"]         ┆ ["5", "6"]      ┆ [11, 16]    ┆ [[], []]                        │
│ ["s1_6"]                 ┆ ["1"]           ┆ [6]         ┆ [[]]                            │
└──────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

Then I can do:
Code 2
df = (
        df.with_columns(
        ).explode(pl.col("id","str_id","source", "m_group"))
        .select(
            pl.col("id","str_id","source", "m_group"),    
        )
        .sort("id")
    )

And obtain following output:
Table 4
┌─────┬──────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ str_id       ┆ source         ┆ m_group        │
│ --- ┆ ---          ┆ ---            ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ str          ┆ str            ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════╪══════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ s1_1         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_4", "6_4"] │
│ 2   ┆ s1_2         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] │
│ 3   ┆ s1_3         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_3", "6_3"] │
│ 4   ┆ s1_4         ┆ 1              ┆ ["6_0"]        │
│ 5   ┆ s1_5         ┆ 1              ┆ ["5_5", "6_5"] │
│ 6   ┆ s1_6         ┆ 1              ┆ []             │
│ 7   ┆ s2_1         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_4"]        │
│ 8   ┆ s2_2         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_2"]        │
│ 9   ┆ s2_3         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_5"]        │
│ 10  ┆ s2_4         ┆ 5              ┆ ["1_3"]        │
│ 11  ┆ s2_5         ┆ 5              ┆ []             │
│ 12  ┆ s3_1         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_4"]        │
│ 13  ┆ s3_2         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_2"]        │
│ 14  ┆ s3_3         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_5"]        │
│ 15  ┆ s3_4         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_3"]        │
│ 16  ┆ s3_5         ┆ 6              ┆ []             │
│ 17  ┆ s3_6         ┆ 6              ┆ ["1_0"]        │
└─────┴──────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘

Question: I'm looking for a way to make it more efficient.
For example the way to set m_status (Table 2) using dataframe from Table 1 is:
Code 3
def set_m_status(df: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    df = (
        df.with_columns(
            l = pl.col.source.len(),
            has1 = pl.col.source.list.contains("1"),
            excl1 = pl.col.source.list.set_difference([1]).list.eval(pl.element() + "_1")
        ).explode(pl.col("id","str_id","source", "m_group"))
        .select(
            pl.col("id","str_id","source", "m_group"),
            m_status = 
            pl.when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.source == "1").then(pl.col.excl1)
            .when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.has1).then(["1"])
            .otherwise([])         
        )
        .sort("id")
    )

    return df

Example data from the Table 2 for the dataframe:
str_id_series = pl.Series("str_id", [["s1_5", "s2_3", "s3_3"], ["s1_2", "s2_2", "s3_2"], ["s1_3", "s2_4", "s3_4"], ["s1_1", "s2_1"], ["s1_4", "s3_6"], ["s2_5", "s3_5"], ["s1_6"]])
source_series = pl.Series("source", [["1", "5", "6"], ["1", "5", "6"], ["1", "5", "6"], ["1", "7"], ["4", "17"], ["5", "6"], ["1"]])
id_series = pl.Series("id", [[5, 9, 14], [2, 8, 13], [3, 10, 15], [1, 7, 12], [4, 17], [11, 16], [6]])

df = pl.DataFrame([str_id_series, source_series, id_series])

EDIT:
Final solution with small tweaks of @jqurious brilliant answer:
def set_m_status_and_m_group(df: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
df = df.with_columns(group_id = 
        pl.struct("partition_number", pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("source", "partition_number"))
        .rank("dense") - 1
    ).with_columns(
        l = pl.len().over("group_id"),
        has1 = (pl.col.source == 1).any().over("group_id"),
        excl1 = pl.col.source.filter(pl.col.source != 1).over("group_id", mapping_strategy="join"),
        m_group = 
            pl.format("{}_{}",
                pl.col.source.filter(pl.col.source != 1),
                pl.col.group_id
            )
            .over("group_id", mapping_strategy="join"),
        m_group_other = pl.format("1_{}", pl.col.group_id).cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8))
    ).select(
        pl.col("id", "str_id", "source"),
        pl.when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.source == 1)
        .then(pl.col.excl1.cast(pl.List(pl.String)).list.eval(pl.element() + "_1"))
        .when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.has1).then(["1_1"])
        .otherwise([])
        .alias("m_status"),
        pl.col("m_group", "m_group_other"),
    ).select(
        pl.col("id", "str_id", "source", "m_status"),
        pl.when(pl.col.source == 1)
        .then(pl.col.m_group)
        .when(pl.col.source != 1, pl.col.m_status.list.contains("1_1"))
        .then(pl.col.m_group_other)
        .otherwise([])
        .alias("m_group"),
    )
return df


df = (
pl.read_csv(b"""
id,str_id,partition_number,source,type,state,quantity,price,m_group,m_status
1,s1_1,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
2,s1_2,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
3,s1_3,222,1,B,2,20,150.0,,
4,s1_4,333,1,C,1,30,200.0,,
5,s1_5,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
6,s1_6,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
7,s2_1,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
8,s2_2,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
9,s2_3,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
10,s2_4,222,5,B,2,20,150.0,,
11,s2_5,444,5,D,1,40,250.0,,
12,s3_1,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
13,s3_2,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
14,s3_3,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
15,s3_4,222,6,B,2,20,150.0,,
16,s3_5,444,6,D,1,40,250.0,,
17,s3_6,333,6,C,1,30,200.0,,
""".strip()
)
.with_columns(
    pl.col("m_group", "m_status").cast(pl.List(pl.String)).fill_null([])
)
)

df = set_m_status_and_m_group(df)
print(df)

┌─────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ str_id ┆ source ┆ m_status       ┆ m_group        │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ list[str]      ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ s1_1   ┆ 1      ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ ["5_0", "6_0"] │
│ 2   ┆ s1_2   ┆ 1      ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] │
│ 3   ┆ s1_3   ┆ 1      ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ ["5_4", "6_4"] │
│ 4   ┆ s1_4   ┆ 1      ┆ ["6_1"]        ┆ ["6_5"]        │
│ 5   ┆ s1_5   ┆ 1      ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] │
│ 6   ┆ s1_6   ┆ 1      ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 7   ┆ s2_1   ┆ 5      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_0"]        │
│ 8   ┆ s2_2   ┆ 5      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 9   ┆ s2_3   ┆ 5      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_2"]        │
│ 10  ┆ s2_4   ┆ 5      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_4"]        │
│ 11  ┆ s2_5   ┆ 5      ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 12  ┆ s3_1   ┆ 6      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_0"]        │
│ 13  ┆ s3_2   ┆ 6      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 14  ┆ s3_3   ┆ 6      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_2"]        │
│ 15  ┆ s3_4   ┆ 6      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_4"]        │
│ 16  ┆ s3_5   ┆ 6      ┆ []             ┆ []             │
│ 17  ┆ s3_6   ┆ 6      ┆ ["1_1"]        ┆ ["1_5"]        │
└─────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘ 


If you use the last approach given to the previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78720381 it seems like this is essentially the same as how excl1 is created (but with the addition of using the "group id" to create the strings)?

@jqurious yes, it can probably be very similar but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried using generator to set m_group for every row in Table 1, but next(gen) runs once only. I can't figure out how to implement int_range inside there. It's problematic because for m_status I set the same value for every row per source if conditions are met. For m_group I need to set different values for every row per source and also the linked value for a linked source has to be set in appriopriate row. I don't know if it can be done in parrarel there. I just need to optimize my current solution I think.

I've had to add a reply as an answer. If I understand correctly, it's basically the same as your previous question with an added group id. I'm not sure on best practices, perhaps you should modify your original question and ask the answerer for an additional response.

Please do not accept this as an answer. (I cannot fit it into a comment)
What you want to do looks to be a slight modification of the previous question that has already been answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78720381/

Except you want to add in a "group_id" for the m_group strings?
df = (
   pl.read_csv(b"""
id,str_id,partition_number,source,type,state,quantity,price,m_group,m_status
1,s1_1,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
2,s1_2,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
3,s1_3,222,1,B,2,20,150.0,,
4,s1_4,333,1,C,1,30,200.0,,
5,s1_5,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
6,s1_6,111,1,A,1,10,100.0,,
7,s2_1,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
8,s2_2,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
9,s2_3,111,5,A,1,10,100.0,,
10,s2_4,222,5,B,2,20,150.0,,
11,s2_5,444,5,D,1,40,250.0,,
12,s3_1,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
13,s3_2,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
14,s3_3,111,6,A,1,10,100.0,,
15,s3_4,222,6,B,2,20,150.0,,
16,s3_5,444,6,D,1,40,250.0,,
17,s3_6,333,6,C,1,30,200.0,,
""".strip()
   )
   .with_columns(
      pl.col("m_group", "m_status").cast(pl.List(pl.String)).fill_null([])
   )
)

(
    df
    .with_columns(group_id = 
        pl.struct("partition_number", pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("source", "partition_number"))
          .rank("dense") - 1
    )
    .with_columns(
        l = pl.len().over("group_id"),
        has1 = (pl.col.source == 1).any().over("group_id"),
        excl1 = pl.col.source.filter(pl.col.source != 1).over("group_id", mapping_strategy="join"),
        m_group = 
            pl.format("{}_{}",
                pl.col.source.filter(pl.col.source != 1),
                pl.col.group_id
            )
            .over("group_id", mapping_strategy="join"),
        m_group_other = pl.format("1_{}", pl.col.group_id)
    )
    .select(
        pl.col("id", "str_id", "source", "group_id"),
        pl.when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.source == 1)
          .then(pl.col.excl1)
          .when(pl.col.l >= 2, pl.col.has1).then([1])
          .otherwise([])        
          .alias("m_status"),
        pl.col("m_group", "m_group_other")
    ) 
)

shape: (17, 7)
┌─────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ id  ┆ str_id ┆ source ┆ group_id ┆ m_status  ┆ m_group        ┆ m_group_other │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---            ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    ┆ u32      ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]      ┆ str           │
╞═════╪════════╪════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ s1_1   ┆ 1      ┆ 0        ┆ [5, 6]    ┆ ["5_0", "6_0"] ┆ 1_0           │
│ 2   ┆ s1_2   ┆ 1      ┆ 1        ┆ [5, 6]    ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ 1_1           │
│ 3   ┆ s1_3   ┆ 1      ┆ 4        ┆ [5, 6]    ┆ ["5_4", "6_4"] ┆ 1_4           │
│ 4   ┆ s1_4   ┆ 1      ┆ 5        ┆ [6]       ┆ ["6_5"]        ┆ 1_5           │
│ 5   ┆ s1_5   ┆ 1      ┆ 2        ┆ [5, 6]    ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] ┆ 1_2           │
│ 6   ┆ s1_6   ┆ 1      ┆ 3        ┆ []        ┆ []             ┆ 1_3           │
│ 7   ┆ s2_1   ┆ 5      ┆ 0        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_0", "6_0"] ┆ 1_0           │
│ 8   ┆ s2_2   ┆ 5      ┆ 1        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ 1_1           │
│ 9   ┆ s2_3   ┆ 5      ┆ 2        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] ┆ 1_2           │
│ 10  ┆ s2_4   ┆ 5      ┆ 4        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_4", "6_4"] ┆ 1_4           │
│ 11  ┆ s2_5   ┆ 5      ┆ 6        ┆ []        ┆ ["5_6", "6_6"] ┆ 1_6           │
│ 12  ┆ s3_1   ┆ 6      ┆ 0        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_0", "6_0"] ┆ 1_0           │
│ 13  ┆ s3_2   ┆ 6      ┆ 1        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] ┆ 1_1           │
│ 14  ┆ s3_3   ┆ 6      ┆ 2        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_2", "6_2"] ┆ 1_2           │
│ 15  ┆ s3_4   ┆ 6      ┆ 4        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["5_4", "6_4"] ┆ 1_4           │
│ 16  ┆ s3_5   ┆ 6      ┆ 6        ┆ []        ┆ ["5_6", "6_6"] ┆ 1_6           │
│ 17  ┆ s3_6   ┆ 6      ┆ 5        ┆ [1]       ┆ ["6_5"]        ┆ 1_5           │
└─────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘

And you want to choose m_group or m_group_other depending on source == 1

This is a brilliant answer, thank you. I modified it slightly to make the output exactly as I wanted. I edited the question with final code.
As you can see I had to call .select() twice as I couldn't perform pl.col.m_status.list.contains("1_1") in the same select statement that m_status was being computed in. I guess it's parrarelized and it simply doesn't exist at the time of execution when computing m_group. Do you think this can be done differently to not call .select() twice?
